# Get the content from <xml> using regex

Tags: xml, regex

I have string like this:

```
<?xml>
<some>
    <tag>
    </tag>
</some>
<data>
    Here replace ' with ''
</data>
</xml>
```

where I need to take only the contents within `<?xml></xml>` that is:

```
<some>
    <tag>
    </tag>
</some>
<data>
    Here replace ' with ''
</data>
```

I tried the regex: `<?xml>.</xml>` but that doesnt work.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to,

```
(?s)<\?xml>(.*?)<\/xml>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qN1fR9/1)

Comment: thanks that works. But I want to take the `'` inside all the tags. How do i it? I tried `(?s)<\?xml>(')<\/xml>`. But doesnt work

Comment: did you want to remove `'`?

Comment: Yes, actualy to replace `'` with `''`, so need to find `'`